# Determing SIM/network/carrier lock status in software

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sim-unlocking, ussd

Is there a way to determine if a Galaxy S3 (i747, running 4.1 JB, stock ROM, but with root) is currently carrier locked in software (i.e. without needing to obtain and insert a different network's SIM).

Apparently there used to be a USSD code to do this (*#SIMLOCK#), but that appears to no longer work.

Comment: try `*#service#`?

Comment: @t0mm13b - Nope, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it but it is way more complicated than borrowing a SIM card. The SIM card does not even have to be activated (have service)... just have different MCC/MNC from your carrier.

To do it the "hard" way you would need to:

1. find, download, install drivers for Qualcomm DIAG interface
2. find, download, install [QXDM](http://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/qxdm-professionaltm-qualcomm-extensible-diagnostic-monitor)
3. find how to switch your phone into the DIAG mode (DIAG interface does not enumerate in normal mode)
4. find the QXDM command to query the subsidy lock status
5. find how to interpret the result you would get
6. come back and post the detailed solution